# How to remove language from canon camera?

Tags: canon, camera-settings

I want to remove unused languages from a Canon EOS camera.

Is there any way I can do it myself?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit your question to explain the specific problem that the unused languages are causing you? We may be able to give you more helpful answers then. Thanks!

Comment: To avoid unfamiliar environment if someone changes it to different language.

Comment: I'd suggest your problem is giving the camera to people who change the language; anyone who did that to one of my cameras without good reason would never be touching it again.

Comment: Kids can do it by mistake. :) But no blame or yell to kids.

Comment: If they're old enough to do the sequence "Menu / (Find appropriate page) / Language / Suomi", they're old enough to understand "Don't mess with stuff".

Comment: In that case, "Vittu Perkele!" is an appropriate opening sentence for the discussion :) (j/k, don't ;) )

Comment: Parents can take responsibility and keep inappropriate things away from the hands of their children, too.

Comment: I think it's a fair question tbh (answer is you can't, as Romeo states below, though). It's not for other users here to start telling someone how to parent their children.

Comment: I'm surprised by the focus on language, because that one is innocuous and easily detected. There are other settings that are much less obvious and that can really mess you up. One would dream of a lock password on settings, or consider that a camera should be carefully reset after being in foreign hands.

Comment: I would expect *any* camera to have the same menu layout and menu items sequence in each and every language. So if you know the menu sequence, it should be quite easy to set it back to your favorite language.

Comment: @MrUpsidown, for Canon cameras you do not need to remember the menus because language menu have special icon (which do not change when you change the language) https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART173736

Comment: @RomeoNinov well you still need to remember in which setup menu (2) it is and what the icon looks like :)

Comment: @MrUpsidown, there are not so many menus, you just walk through all of them :) And it is on most of Canon cameras is one of the last menu in right side.

Comment: @MrUpsidown That's what online PDF copies of the manual for each camera are for. Use the manual for the language you understand and it will walk you straight to where you need to go, regardless of what language is showing on the camera's screen. All you need to do is count the correct tabs and lines in each menu.

Comment: *if you know the menu sequence* - that's exaclty what I have said. I haven't said you need to remember it by heart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is just English and wanna remove all fk languages you don't know, you can do that with [Tornado EOS](https://tornadosw.com/tornado-eos.php) Windows app. It will do the trick. You have to pay $30 for a 5-day license. It supports all Canon EOS DSLR and mirrorless cameras(and Nikon cameras). You have to unlock Language mode. once it's enabled, You will have only English and Japanese. Good luck!

### Canon EOS

[image]

### Nikon

[image]

Comment: Does this app support multiple camera at once?
Meaning, after buy the license, can manage only one camera within 5 days?
Can I use it for Canon and Nitkon, I have those 2 camera and hope to handle both with current license.

Comment: Also, My Nikon camera has already enabled language mode by default.
In this case, How to do remove other unnecessary languages?

Comment: Yes. you can use it for multiple cameras as long as the license doesn't expire. I'm not quite sure about Nikon as I'm a Canon camera holder. you can directly ask the developer who developed this app through the website.

Comment: Alex, yeah, it worked perfectly with several cameras until license expired.
Also, Nikon would work fine too, even though it worked differently compare with Canon.
I had to select Region to Japan.
Thanks for your solution.

Comment: Awesome, sounds like you're also a pro camera enthusiast)) good luck! @ClusterH

Comment: Seems like the web site is reported as it may contain malware.

Comment: @RomeoNinov There are enough reports of Tornado EOS being used successfully that I'm going to assume that's a false positive unless there is strong evidence otherwise; in particular, see [this post](https://www.magiclantern.fm/forum/index.php?topic=23241.msg211557#msg211557) from the author (or someone claiming to be the author) on the Magic Lantern forums.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, site infection can happen in this moment. But of course everyone decides for themselves.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: you can't

These texts are stored in to the firmware of the camera. So to remove them you should create new firmware for the camera which is not a simple process. You can check more about the subject [here](https://magiclantern.fm/).

And reconsider your request. Usually 99% of the settings (including language) in to the camera are done once and you can even forget about them. So I do not see serious reason why existence of other menu languages should bother you.

Comment: Thanks, Romeo. Unfortunately, my camera is EOS 200D II which is still not supported by the tool you mentioned.
I still wish for a positive answer to my question. :)
I will see if there comes more answers and accept your answer after a while.

Answer (score 1):

@Romeo suggested hacking the firmware using [MagicLantern](https://magiclantern.fm/)   If this software has not yet been customised for your camera, you could download the source code and have a go yourself, that's the beauty of open source software!

If your problem is other people randomly changing the language setting, I might suggest that anyone capable of hacking firmware shouldn't have any problem with negotiating the camera's Language setting, even if it is currently displayed in the wrong language.  I mean, it's always going to be in the same place in the menu tree!

Comment: Maybe you get me wrong. I do not suggest to use ML. I want to demonstrate to OP how complicate can be to build custom firmware.

Comment: @Romeo Ninov - well, you DID suggest that tool could do that sort of thing!

Comment: you can backup your settings from ML, and restore them if you can't find the lang menu under the new/wrong language.