# How to remove language from sony camera?

Tags: camera-settings, sony

I want to remove unused languages from a Sony hx400, a6400 camera.

Is there any way I can do it myself?

Comment: What goal are you attempting to accomplish here? (i.e. how will this improve your photography). See also the [comments here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/128288/how-to-remove-language-from-canon-camera)

Answer (score 2):

In general all the settings, menus, languages are stored in the firmware. And If you want to change something, in your case remove language, you should disassemble the firmware file, make your changes, compile and pack. And install.

And if the firmware is digitally signed and install procedure check the signature (not sure, pure speculation) you are (again) out of luck because only Sony can sign it with proper key.

With two words: **forget it**

Comment: Two words: "forget it" (for the standard US English phrasing ;)

Comment: @FreeMan, or simplifying with one word: **no** :D

Comment: @FreeMan Or back to one word: fuggedaboutit

Comment: That's standard New Yorker phrasing, @PeterM. Not sure I'd call that standard English. :D

Answer (score 0):

This project can help you to change some settings, that you otherwise couldn't, on some Sony cameras:

https://github.com/ma1co/OpenMemories-Tweak

According to this page, your HX400 is supported, but the A6400 is not:

https://github.com/ma1co/OpenMemories-Framework/blob/master/docs/Cameras.md

Use at your own risk.

Comment: From the documentation, this does the exact opposite of what the OP wants and *unlocks* all languages. Can you confirm it allows languages to be removed as requested?

Comment: @Phillip Kendall - I cannot confirm that, I have neither of those cameras.

Comment: Actually, it says it will "unlock the language menu".  This might or might not do what the OP wants.


I get that it's unknown from the github page if the Tweak addresses too many languages, as opposed to the wrong language, which is a more common use case.  In fact, I didn't state that it would.  I thought this was the best chance the OP had, since everyone else basically told him to GTFO.